# Flutter error: Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, flutter

pls how can I resolve this flutter error

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_udid'.

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_udid:classpath'.
   Could not download bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0)
      Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.9.0/bundletool-0.9.0.jar'.
         Read timed out
   Could not download kotlin-stdlib.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar'.
            Remote host closed connection during handshake
   Could not download gradle-download-task.jar (de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:3.4.3)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/3.4.3/gradle-download-task-3.4.3.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/3.4.3/gradle-download-task-3.4.3.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
   Could not download httpmime.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.6/httpmime-4.5.6.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download httpclient.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download httpcore.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download error_prone_annotations.jar (com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.3.1)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.1/error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.3.1/error_prone_annotations-2.3.1.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download kotlin-script-runtime.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.50)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-script-runtime/1.3.50/kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.50.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-script-runtime/1.3.50/kotlin-script-runtime-1.3.50.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download kotlin-daemon-embeddable.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.3.50)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download trove4j.jar (org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/intellij/deps/trove4j/1.0.20181211/trove4j-1.0.20181211.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/intellij/deps/trove4j/1.0.20181211/trove4j-1.0.20181211.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download kotlin-build-common.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-build-common:1.3.50)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-build-common/1.3.50/kotlin-build-common-1.3.50.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-build-common/1.3.50/kotlin-build-common-1.3.50.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download kotlinx-coroutines-core.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.1.1/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.1.1/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.1.1.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download kotlin-stdlib-common.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar'.
         Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download trove4j.jar (org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824)
       Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar'.
        Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar'.
            jcenter.bintray.com
   Could not download commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10)
      Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar'.
            > jcenter.bintray.com

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 2s
  Command: /home/benny/Documents/Afiaanyi/mobile_app_codes/android/gradlew app:properties
```

pls can someone suggest how I can fix this errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the above url address into your browser and see if you can access them 
for example  this one https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-embeddable/1.3.50/

Also try to see if you have proxy or network issue to access the internet.